# How can i use the mptcp socket api?

Tags: linux, sockets, mptcp

I followed [this](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureMPTCP) to use the MPTCP Socket API.
my mptcp setting (mptcp_enabled=2

[image]

I wrote the echo server(localhost) and client in c.
And I used `tcpdump` to capture between(server - client).

But I failed, because packet not with the mptcp option.
this is tcpdump result. (test message is "hello")

[image: test message is "hello"]

This is server source code

[image]

And this client source code

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: Please post your code as plain text in the question, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RL87.png).. 
My problem is that the server used the localhost address.